# JQuery DatePicker Default Date 18 years ago

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to get my jquery datepicker to default to open on 18 years in the past (user must be 18 or over to use app) and I don't want them to be able to select any date that isn't 18 years or more in the past. I have this code but I can't get it to work apart from showing the default todays date. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",'1998-01-01');
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The date format in `SetDate` method seems wrong . From the api doc, I would write it `01/01/1998`

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I've changed the format but today's date keeps popping up as the default. Any other idea?

Comment: Also see `MaxDate` property of the widget that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the datepicker by datepicker method and setDate

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate','01/01/1998');
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXyoqb